# Eager loading generating slower queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading, will-paginate

I'm optimizing my app and noticed something interesting.  I originally had this statement in my controller

```
@votes = Vote.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order=>"created_at DESC")
```

and this in my view

```
<% @votes.each do |vote| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= vote.user.display_name %></td>
...
```

I tried changing the controller to use eager loading:

```
@votes = Vote.includes(:user).paginate(:page => params[:page],
  :order=>"created_at DESC")
```

In doing so, I noticed that my ActiveRecord query time to load votes/index **doubled from 180 ms to 440 ms**.  The number of queries was successfully cut down with eager loading.  However, I found this one time-consuming query in the eager load situation **only**:

```
  SQL (306.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "votes"."id") FROM "votes" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "votes"."user_id"
```

Why is my code requesting a count on a left outer join?  It's not present in the non-eager-load case.  In the non-eager-load case, this is the closest statement I can find:

```
  SQL (30.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes"
```

Is this something related to paginate?  Is it some combination of the two?

Comment: I ran into this today as well. I was doing an include on a habtm association and it ended up producing a query that consisted of every unique id for the model. Here's [all that i found on the issue](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issuesearch?state=open&q=includes#issue/72)

Comment: you'd get reputation points for my upvote if you'd posted this as an answer =P  I think your problem will be solved by Malte's solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that query seems to be generated by the pagination plugin. This query is necessary to estimate the total number of pages.

But if you know the number of records anyway (by doing a simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes"` before), you can pass that number to will_paginate with the `:total_entries` option!

(See [WillPaginate::Finder::ClassMethods](http://rubydoc.info/gems/will_paginate/2.3.15/WillPaginate/Finder/ClassMethods) for more info.)

Btw, have you created an index for `votes.user_id`? May be that is slowing down the query. I'm wondering why the `DISTINCT` clause should take up so much time as `id` probably already has a unique constraint (if not, try adding one).

Comment: Yes!  That took that SQL request out!  Thanks!  I simply used `c = Vote.count` and `@votes = Vote.includes(:user).paginate(:page => params[:page], :order=>"created_at DESC", :total_entries => c)`

Comment: To answer your question, yes, I have an index on `votes.user_id`.  I think the reason the query is taking so long is that it's doing an outer join?  I'm still puzzled why I get this query from will_paginate when I use `includes` but not without.